# QT sinal de C++ para QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Estou tentando com QT 5 + QML criar um aplicação onde após abrir o arquivo utilizando o `fileDialog` ele retorne uma mensagem por um sinal do QT.

A aplicação faz a abertura utilizando um QML e iniciando uma chamada a um `SLOT` na classe responsável. Esta classe realiza a leitura e posteriormente fará alguns trabalhos a mais e retornaria por um `SIGNAL` o trabalho terminado para ser apresentado.

O código da main segue a baixo:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQml>
#include "imagefilter.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);

 ImageFilter filtro;
 qmlRegisterType<ImageFilter>("ImageFilter", 1, 0, "ImageFilter");

 QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
 engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("filtro", &filtro);
 engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

 return app.exec();
}
```

A classe responsável pelo trabalho das imagens:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

class ImageFilter : public QObject
{
 Q_OBJECT
public:
 explicit ImageFilter(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
 void teste(const QString &path);
public slots:
 void receiveImage(const QString path);

};
```

> O `signal teste` é apenas um teste que estou realizando para validar se consigo receber as informações posteriormente retornaria um `QImage`.

O `SLOT` que faz a chamada do `SIGNAL` para simplificar o teste.

```
void ImageFilter::receiveImage(QString path)
{
 qDebug() << path;
 emit teste("Teste");
}
```

Por fim o QML, vou postar apenas a parte responsável por receber o `SIGNAL` pois a parte de `SLOT` não tenho problema nenhum.

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import ImageFilter 1.0

ImageFilter {
  onTeste: image2.text: path
}
```

O que seria esperado de funcionar pois utilizei da documentação do qt-project.org, porem o onTeste não é chamado pelo menos o texto no local não é alterado. Neste caso utilizei o `qmlRegisterType` pois não descobri uma forma de trabalhar igual a utilizada para fazer chamadas a SLOTS no C++ com `engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("filtro", &filtro);`.

Se alguém puder ajudar em como receber estes sinais.
Grato!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semi resolvido, por algum motivo o Qt 5 não esta aceitando o **handler** da forma.

Na main:

```
qmlRegisterType<ImageFilter>("org.image.filter", 1, 0, "ImageFilter");
```

No qml:

```
ImageFilter {
    id: document
    onUrlChanged: {
        console.log("fui alterado")
    }
}
```

Para resolver, fiz o seguinte na main:

```
ImageFilter filter
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("filtro", &filter);
```

Na classe ImageFilter adicionei um `Q_PROPERTY` vou colocar o código inteiro que fica mais fácil de se visualizar:

```
class Filter : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(QUrl url READ url WRITE setUrl NOTIFY urlChanged)

public:
   explicit Filter(QObject *parent = 0);

   void setUrl(const QUrl url){
      if (m_url != url) {
         m_url = url;
         emit urlChanged();
      }
   }

   QUrl url() const {
      return m_url;
   }

signals:
   void urlChanged();

public slots:
   void imageSlot(const QUrl &url){
      qDebug() << url;
      setUrl(url);
   }

private:
   QUrl m_url;

};
```

E no qml utilizei:

```
Connections {
    target: filtro
    onUrlChanged: {
        console.log("url alterada")
        image2.text = filtro.url
    }
}
```

Com isto consegui fazer o handler funcionar, algumas coisas estão diferentes, neste caso meu signal é urlChanged();

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja meramente um erro de sintaxe com o seu arquivo QML:

```
ImageFilter {
  onTeste: image2.text = path
}
```

O valor depois de `onTeste` deve ser um código de javascript válido, não uma definição de outra propriedade. Pode ter mais de uma linha usando chaves `{ ... }`.

Comment: Sim, mas até onde a documentação informava utilizar de {...}apenas para mais de uma linha mesmo, como o que desejo é apenas a alteração de um texto não existe a necessidade de se utilizar {...}.